# Custom UIImageView Border

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make a border like this:

[image: Screen]

With this code:

```
self.slot1.layer.cornerRadius = self.slot1.bounds.height / 2
self.slot1.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
self.slot1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
```

It produces:

### [image: Screen2]

How can i add a "spacing" between the border and the actual image?

Comment: Just embed it in UIView make rounded corners of view give border and color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using below extension

```
extension UIImage {
    func imageWithInsets(insets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
            CGSize(width: self.size.width + insets.left + insets.right,
                   height: self.size.height + insets.top + insets.bottom), false, self.scale)
        let _ = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let origin = CGPoint(x: insets.left, y: insets.top)
        self.draw(at: origin)
        let imageWithInsets = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return imageWithInsets
    }
}
```

Use below code to add space between image and border, i add here 20 you can give your own space

```
self.slot1.layer.cornerRadius = self.slot1.bounds.height / 2
self.slot1.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
self.slot1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
let image = self.slot1.image?.imageWithInsets(insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20))
self.slot1.image = image
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to make space in between, take one `UIView` inside that put your `UIImageView`. `UIImageView` should have less `width and height`, then add `corner radius` to both but add `border color` to `UIVIew` only.

Your UI should be like this :

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Sharad, do you have a code to achieve this?

Comment: Achieve what ? Do you have that `Imageview` in Storyboard or nib ? Just make changes there, put `UIVIew` in place of `ImageView` and place `ImageView `inside the `UIView`. Then simply use your code on both of them for `cornerRadius`.

Answer (score 1):

Run in playground

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

let iv = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200, height: 200))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = iv

iv.backgroundColor = .blue
iv.layer.cornerRadius = 100
iv.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
iv.layer.borderWidth = 5
iv.layer.sublayers?.count

let layer2 = CAShapeLayer()
let newFrame = iv.bounds.insetBy(dx: 7, dy: 7)
layer2.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: newFrame, cornerRadius: newFrame.height / 2).cgPath
layer2.frame = iv.bounds
layer2.lineWidth = 5
layer2.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
layer2.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
iv.layer.addSublayer(layer2)
```